# include one Makefile to several other Makefile-s OR how to share Makefile between projects

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have following structure which consists of independent projects that are builded by the same Makefile (the differences are only in `BUILD_TYPE` & `LINKER_TYPE` variables):

```
wakatana@ubuntu:~/make$ ls -1
01-proj
02-proj
03-proj
04-proj
```

Common Makefile:

```
BUILD_TYPE := cargo
.DEFAULT_GOAL := default
FULL_PATH := $(shell readlink -f './build')
DIR_NAME := $(shell basename $(shell pwd))
LINKER_TYPE := none

ifeq ($(BUILD_TYPE), cmake)
symlink: symlink_cmake
default: build_cmake
else ifeq ($(BUILD_TYPE), cargo)
symlink: symlink_cargo
default: build_cargo
endif

ifeq ($(LINKER_TYPE), static)
all: symlink build_static
else ifeq ($(LINKER_TYPE), dynamic)
all: symlink build_dynamic
else ifeq ($(LINKER_TYPE), none)
all: symlink default
endif

ramdisk:
    sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1024m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk

build_cmake:
    rm -rf ./build/*
    cmake -S . -B$(FULL_PATH)
    cmake --build $(FULL_PATH)

build_cargo:
    cargo build --release --verbose

symlink_cmake:
    @ echo "creating symlinks for cmake"
    @ rm -rf ./build
    @ mkdir -p /mnt/ramdisk/$(DIR_NAME)/build
    @ ln -s /mnt/ramdisk/$(DIR_NAME)/build build

symlink_cargo:
    @ echo "creating symlinks for cargo"
    @ rm -rf ./target
    @ mkdir -p /mnt/ramdisk/$(DIR_NAME)/target
    @ ln -s /mnt/ramdisk/$(DIR_NAME)/target target

build_static: default
    gcc main.c -o myprog -I ./include_c/ ./target/release/libmylib.a -lpthread -ldl

build_dynamic: default
    gcc -o myprog -I ./include_c main.c -L ./target/release/ -l:libmylib.so
    @ # export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:"./target/release/"

clean:
    rm -f myprog a.out
    rm -rf ./target ./build
```

Is it possible to have one Makefile in parent folder and somehow to include it to all other projects where (`BUILD_TYPE` & `LINKER_TYPE` will be set for particular project)? Advises for making better Makefile are also welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. It is possible to use `include` command of `make`. My structure now look like this:

```
wakatana@ubuntu:~/make$ ls -1
01-proj
02-proj
03-proj
04-proj
makefile.mk
```

content of `makefile.mk`:

```
ifeq ($(BUILD_TYPE), cmake)
symlink: symlink_cmake
default: build_cmake
else ifeq ($(BUILD_TYPE), cargo)
symlink: symlink_cargo
default: build_cargo
endif

ifeq ($(LINKER_TYPE), static)
all: symlink build_static
else ifeq ($(LINKER_TYPE), dynamic)
all: symlink build_dynamic
else ifeq ($(LINKER_TYPE), none)
all: symlink default
endif

ramdisk:
    sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1024m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk

build_cmake:
    rm -rf ./build/*
    cmake -S . -B$(FULL_PATH)
    cmake --build $(FULL_PATH)

build_cargo:
    cargo build --release --verbose

symlink_cmake:
    @ echo "creating symlinks for cmake"
    @ rm -rf ./build
    @ mkdir -p /mnt/ramdisk/$(DIR_NAME)/build
    @ ln -s /mnt/ramdisk/$(DIR_NAME)/build build

symlink_cargo:
    @ echo "creating symlinks for cargo"
    @ rm -rf ./target
    @ mkdir -p /mnt/ramdisk/$(DIR_NAME)/target
    @ ln -s /mnt/ramdisk/$(DIR_NAME)/target target

build_static: default
    gcc main.c -o myprog -I ./include_c/ ./target/release/libmylib.a -lpthread -ldl
    @ # gcc main.c -I ./include_c/ -L./target/release/ -lmylib -lpthread -ldl
    @ # gcc main.c -I ./include_c/ -L./target/release/ -l:libmylib.a -lpthread -ldl
    @ # vsetko nalinkuje staticky (aj glibc) neda sa ani cez ldd pozriet
    @ # gcc -static main.c -I ./include_c/ -L./target/release/ -l:libmylib.a -lpthread -ldl

build_dynamic: default
    gcc -o myprog -I ./include_c main.c -L ./target/release/ -l:libmylib.so
    @ # gcc -o myprog -I ./include_c main.c -L ./target/release/ -lmylib
    @ # export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:"./target/release/"

clean:
    rm -f myprog a.out
    rm -rf ./target ./build
```

Content of `Makefile` in particular project (`BUILD_TYPE` & `LINKER_TYPE` may vary in particular project):

```
BUILD_TYPE := cmake
.DEFAULT_GOAL := default
FULL_PATH := $(shell readlink -f './build')
DIR_NAME := $(shell basename $(shell pwd))
LINKER_TYPE := none
include ../makefile.mk
```